# How to override the way a combobox finds the selecteditem in its itemssource

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, mvvm

Given the following XAML fragment:

`<ComboBox ItemsSource={Binding ListOfItems} SelectedItem={Binding CurrentItem, Mode=TwoWay}/>`

It would seem that if the ViewModel assigns it's CurrentItem property to an instance of one of the ListOfItems then the ComboBox will display the correct values.

However if the ViewModel assigns CurrentItem to a "clone" of an instance in ListOfItems the ComboBox isn't able to find the SelectedItem in it's ItemsSource and so no selected Item is displayed.

How do I override the way ComboBox finds it's selectedItem in its ListOfItems, such that it operates by value, and not by reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you considered overwriting the Equals method in your bound objects?
That would work ;)

You can also do add a SelectedValue property to the view model and add SelectedValuePath and SelectedValue with a TwoWay Binding to your view.
Here's a quick example:
View:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <SilverlightApplication2:TestCollection x:Key="TestCollection" />
        <SilverlightApplication2:TestSelectedItem x:Key="TestSelectedItem"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid 
        x:Name="LayoutRoot" 
        Background="White">
        <ComboBox 
            DisplayMemberPath="Text"
            SelectedValuePath="Id"
            SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue, Source={StaticResource TestSelectedItem}, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Height="25"
            DataContext="{StaticResource TestCollection}" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Tests}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Quick and dirty code behind ;)

```
public class Test
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestCollection
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Test> Tests { get; set; }

        public TestCollection()
        {
            this.Tests = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
            Tests.Add(new Test{ Id = 1, Text = "one"});
            Tests.Add(new Test { Id = 2, Text = "two" });
            Tests.Add(new Test { Id = 3, Text = "three" });
        }

    }

    public class TestSelectedItem
    {
        public Test SelectedItem { get; set; }

        private int _selectedValue;
        public int SelectedValue
        {
            get { return _selectedValue; }
            set { _selectedValue = value; }
        }

        public TestSelectedItem()
        {
            SelectedItem = new Test {Id = 2, Text = "two"};
            SelectedValue = 2;
        }

    }

    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

BR,

TJ

Comment: I first tried the override of equals but that didn't seem to work.  Setting the SelectedValuePath and SelectedValue did work.